# Unital ring $R$ such that $a^2=a$ for every $a\in R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

**Question**: Let $R$ be a unital ring such that $a^2=a$ for every $a\in R$. Prove that $\mathrm{char}(R)=2$ and $R$ is commutative. Give infinitely many examples of such rings.

It's very easy to show that $\mathrm{char}(R)=2$ and $R$ is commutative, but I'm a little stuck as to how to give infinitely many examples.

Comment: If 4=2 then subtracting 2 from both sides gives 2=0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such rings are called Boolean rings.

$$a+a=(a+a)^2= a^2+a^2+a^2+a^2= a+a+a+a$$
$$\implies a+a=0$$

In particular $1+1=0$ and $\operatorname{char}(R)=2$.

Commutativity I leave as an exercise. You can do something analogously. Let me know if you need more hints on this.

For the examples, here is a general construction: Let $X$ be a set with $|X|\geq2$ (to avoid the trivial ring) and consider the power set $2^X$. Make this into a ring by defining

$$A+B= A\triangle B:= (A\setminus B)\cup(B\setminus A)$$
$$A\cdot B= A \cap B$$

Check that this is a ring with identity $X$. Clearly we have $A^2=A$ for every subset of $X$, so this ring satisfies your property.

Now, you can make an infinite collection of non-isomorphic rings by considering this ring and making the power set of this ring into a ring in the same way. By Cantor's theorem, these two rings have different cardinalities hence are not isomorphic. Continue this construction to get an infinite countable family of such rings.

---

Addendum: We have to exclude the trivial ring $R=\{0\}$ since this ring has characteristic $0$ (or $1$, depending on your definition) and satisfies your condition.

Comment: Of course you can. Define $X_1= X$ with the ring structure I wrote dow. Define $X_2= \mathcal{P}(X_1)$  and put the ring structure on it I said. Put $X_3=\mathcal{P}(X_2)$ and put the ring structure on it. Continue this process (via induction). We get a sequence $X_1,X_2, \dots$ of Boolean rings and $|X_1|<|X_2|< \dots$  so the rings in this sequence can't be isomorphic because they have different cardinalities.

Comment: You can actually get a simpler family of rings. Consider $X_n=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $R_n=\mathcal P(X_n)$ (this gives all powers of $2$, while you're getting the sequence of cardinalities $1,2,4,16,65536,\ldots$). Of course your examples work just as well...

Comment: Yes, that's even simpler. Good catch.

Comment: @fordjones The reason for which that sequence of cardinalities is the one I indicated is just that $|\mathcal P(X)|=2^{|X|}$, so we're getting $2^0=1$, then $2^1=2$, then $2^2=4$, and then $2^4=16$, skipping $2^3=8$; then $2^{16}=65536$, skipping $2^5,\ldots,2^{15}$. But it really doesn't matter. It's just that it would actually be simpler...

Comment: It is just basic set theory, but you have to check several cases.

Answer (score 2):

Elaborating on Mindlack's answer, from $(x+y)^2 = x^2 + y^2$, we obtain
$$a^2 + a^2 = (a+a)^2 = (a+a)(a+a)= a^2 + a^2 + a^2 + a^2,$$
whence $a+a = a^2 + a^2 = 0$, and therefore the characteristic is $2$.

Concerning commutativity, from $x+x=0$, we get $x=-x$, whence
$$a+b = (a+b)^2 = a^2 + b^2 + ab + ba = a + b + ab + ba$$
implies that
$$ab = -ba = ba.$$

To give infinitely many such examples, consider Boolean rings (indeed, these rings satisfying $x^2=x$ are precisely the Boolean rings).
These [are related to Boolean algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_ring#Relation_to_Boolean_algebras), so you only have to think about infinitely many Boolean algebras: for example, the powerset algebras of finite sets.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta What about that? I proved something obvious! Thanks for pointing out. I'll shamelessly use the exact formula from your comment. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help. Have a very nice day/night!